# getting segmentation fault during execution

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am trying to make a tree structure for a specific directory. the path of the directory is entered by the user and is passed to opendir func . the readdir func reads the current directory and is recursively reading subdirectories. I am unable to dubug this program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<limits.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
struct tree{
    char dname[100];
    char fname[200];
    int i;
    struct tree *openf[100];

};

void getinto(char [],char [],struct tree*);
struct dirent *dpointer;
int found=0;
int k=0;

_Bool is_dir(const char* path) {
    struct stat buf;
    stat(path, &buf);
    return S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode);
}

int main() {
char path[100]=".";
DIR *dr;
struct tree *rootnode;
rootnode=(struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
printf("enter path :: ");
scanf("%s",path);
//printf("helllo\n");
rootnode->i=0;
dr=opendir(path);
//printf("helllo\n");
strcpy(rootnode->dname,path);
if((dpointer=readdir(dr))==NULL){
    printf("current directory is empty !!");


}
while ((dpointer=readdir(dr))!=NULL){
    struct tree *rootchild;
    rootchild=(struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    rootnode->openf[rootnode->i++]=rootchild;
    if (strcmp(dpointer->d_name,"..")==0 || strcmp(dpointer->d_name,".")==0 ) 
    continue;
    //printf("helllo\n");
    if(is_dir(dpointer->d_name)){
        printf("%s is directory \n",dpointer->d_name);
        getinto(dpointer->d_name,path,rootchild);
        //printf("helllo loop\n");
        printf("%s is directory \n",dpointer->d_name);

    }
    else{
        strcpy(rootchild->dname,dpointer->d_name);
        //printf("helllo loop\n");
        printf("%s is file \n",dpointer->d_name);
    }
}
closedir(dr);
return 0;
}

void getinto(char sfilename[],char spath[],struct tree* this){
char filename[100],currentpath[100],temp[100];
DIR *d=opendir(currentpath);
strcpy(filename,sfilename);
strcpy(currentpath,spath);
strcat(currentpath,"/");
strcat(currentpath,filename);
printf("helllo function\n");
d=opendir(currentpath);
//printf("helllo function\n");
this->i=0;
while((dpointer=readdir(d))!=NULL){
    struct tree *child;
    child=(struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    this->openf[this->i++]=child;
    if (strcmp(dpointer->d_name,"..")==0 || strcmp(dpointer->d_name,".")==0 ) 
    continue;
    //printf("helllo function loop\n");
    if(is_dir(dpointer->d_name)){
        printf("%s is directory \n",dpointer->d_name);
        getinto(dpointer->d_name,currentpath,child);
        //printf("helllo loop\n");
        printf("%s is directory \n",dpointer->d_name);

    }
    else{
        strcpy(child->dname,dpointer->d_name);
        //printf("helllo loop\n");
        printf("%s is file \n",dpointer->d_name);
    }
}
closedir(d);

}
```

Every time I execute it ends up with a segmentation fault:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I am expecting it to cleanly create a dynamic tree with data of each node as name of file or directory.

Comment: This is the perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger, to trace through 

your code line by line inspecting all variables in scope, to understand what is 

really going on.

Comment: can you please guide me through the steps ... i dont know  how to use gdb

Comment: C'mon, [try this](https://www.google.com/search?q=gdb+how+to).

Comment: Take a look at `getinto` function, [1] `filename` is array with uninitialized content, [2] the call of `strcat` can only work if first string is ended by null terminator.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve your code to get no warnings. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Learn to [debug with `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) on the command line. Use also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: BTW, you might consider using [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)

Comment: followed the above steps .... i guess problem is in is_dir function its not functioning properly can someone check that

Comment: your path-construction is incomplete. (also: `filename[]` is not initialised) Check the return value you get from `stat()`

Comment: @rafix07 how can i rectify that ??? after running above updated code m getting the follwing error:Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:62
62 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
_Bool is_dir(const char* path) {
    struct stat buf;
    stat(path, &buf);
    return S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode);
}
```

`stat` needs pathname of type `char*`.

Syntax:

`int stat(const char *pathname, struct stat *statbuf);`

but you are passing

```
if(is_dir((const char*)dr))
```

`dr` of type `DIR`.

Simply change the `is_dir` calls as below.

```
is_dir(dpointer->d_name) //in main as well as in getinto function
```

---

Also `readdir` will return the entries including

```
.   //current dir
..  //parent dir
```

Hence you need to skip these two entries in `main` otherwise your `opendir` in `getinfo` will fail causing `readdir` in `getinfo` crash.

So skip these entries in `main` as below.

```
while ((dpointer=readdir(dr))!=NULL){
    if (strcmp(dpointer->d_name,"..")==0 || strcmp(dpointer->d_name,".")==0 ) 
    continue;
   .....
   .....
  }
```

Comment: corrected all of the above and made some more changes .... its working halfway ... it breaks when recursive function is called.code updated above

Comment: @wolf_flow I'm not facing any issues with the updated code.

Comment: it occurs when when u have subdirectory in a subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

this code finally worked perfectly for me '

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<limits.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
struct tree{
    char dname[1000];
    char fname[2000];
    int i;
    struct tree *openf[1000];

};

void getinto(char [],char [],struct tree*);
struct dirent *dpointer;
int found=0;
int k=0;

_Bool is_dir(const char* path) {
    struct stat buf;
    stat(path, &buf);
    return S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode);
}

int main() {
char path[1000]=".";
DIR *dr;
struct tree *rootnode;
rootnode=(struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
printf("enter path :: ");
scanf("%s",path);
//printf("helllo\n");
rootnode->i=0;
dr=opendir(path);
//printf("helllo\n");
strcpy(rootnode->dname,path);
if((dpointer=readdir(dr))==NULL){
    printf("current directory is empty !!");


}
while ((dpointer=readdir(dr))!=NULL){
    struct tree *rootchild;
    rootchild=(struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    rootnode->openf[rootnode->i++]=rootchild;
    if (strcmp(dpointer->d_name,"..")==0 || strcmp(dpointer->d_name,".")==0 ) 
    continue;
    //printf("helllo\n");
    if(is_dir(dpointer->d_name)){
        printf("%s is directory \n",dpointer->d_name);
        getinto(dpointer->d_name,path,rootchild);
        //printf("helllo loop\n");
        //printf("%s is directory \n",dpointer->d_name);

    }
    else{
        strcpy(rootchild->dname,dpointer->d_name);
        //printf("helllo loop\n");
        printf("%s is file \n",dpointer->d_name);
    }
}
closedir(dr);
return 0;
}

void getinto(char sfilename[],char spath[],struct tree* this){
char filename[1000],currentpath[1000],temp[1000];
DIR *d=opendir(currentpath);
strcpy(filename,sfilename);
strcpy(currentpath,spath);
strcat(currentpath,"/");
strcat(currentpath,filename);
printf("%s",currentpath);
printf("\nhelllo function\n");
d=opendir(currentpath);
//printf("helllo function\n");
this->i=0;
while((dpointer=readdir(d))!=NULL){
    struct tree *child;
    child=(struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    this->openf[this->i++]=child;
     if (strcmp(dpointer->d_name,"..")==0 || strcmp(dpointer->d_name,".")==0 ) 
     continue;
    //printf("helllo function loop\n");
    if(is_dir(dpointer->d_name)){
        printf("%s is directory \n",dpointer->d_name);
        //getinto(dpointer->d_name,currentpath,child);
        //printf("helllo loop\n");
        printf("%s is directory \n",dpointer->d_name);

    }
    else{
        strcpy(child->dname,dpointer->d_name);
        //printf("helllo loop\n");
        printf("%s is file \n",dpointer->d_name);
    }
}
printf("\niits over!!");
closedir(d);
return ;

}
```

'
thanks for the help y'all !!!